# CreateObject for Excel: Normal Run works, Run as Administrator doesn't?

Tags: excel, vb6, office365

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
On Error GoTo Command1_Click_EH
Dim objXL As Object
Dim wbXL As Object

' ***************

Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' ***************

objXL.ScreenUpdating = False 
Set wbXL = objXL.Workbooks.Add
objXL.Visible = True

Exit Sub

Command1_Click_EH:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Error is

> "ActiveX component can't create object"

at line `CreateObject` when ran as Administrator , otherwise runs successfully.

Error is for **office365** only.

```
version 1906 
Build 11727.2044 Microsoft store
Monthly Channel
```

Comment: Have you run Excel manually from the administrator account?

Comment: @Gserg Yes, it works